# Primes of form $p = \frac{(2^{m_1}-1) (2^{m_2}-1) \cdots }{ (2^{n_1}-1) (2^{n_2}-1)\cdots }$ and BBP-type formulas?

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, prime-numbers, logarithms

In *A Compendium of BBP-Type Formulas for Mathematical Constants*, Bailey gave a list of **prime** $p<2^{43}$ such that $\ln(p)$ has a BBP-type formula.

Excluding $p=2$, and the *Mersenne primes* $M_m = 3, 7, 31, 127, 8191, 131071, 524287$, and *Fermat primes* $F= 5,17,257,65537$, the remaining $35$ are,

> $$p = 11, 13, 19, 29, 37, 41, 43, 61, 73, 109, 113, 151,
>   241, 337, 397, 683, 1321, 1613, 2113, 2731, 5419, 43691, 61681,
>   87211, 174763, 262657, 2796203, 15790321, 18837001,
>   22366891, 4278255361, 4562284561, 2932031007403, 4363953127297,
>   4432676798593$$

Define the Mersenne number $M_m = 2^m-1$. Then,

$$73 = \frac{M_{9}}{M_{3}},\quad 262657 = \frac{M_{27}}{M_{9}},\quad 4432676798593 = \frac{M_{49}}{M_{7}}$$
and *[Wagstaff primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wagstaff_prime)*,

$$11=\frac{M_{10}}{M_{2}\,M_{5}},\quad 43 = \frac{M_{14}}{M_{2}\,M_{7}},\quad 683 = \frac{M_{22}}{M_{2}\,M_{11}},\quad 2731 = \frac{M_{26}}{M_{2}\,M_{13}},\quad 43691 = \frac{M_{34}}{M_{2}\,M_{17}},\quad 174763 = \frac{M_{38}}{M_{2}\,M_{19}},\quad 2796203= \frac{M_{46}}{M_{2}\,M_{23}},\quad 2932031007403= \frac{M_{86}}{M_{2}\,M_{43}}$$
and,

$$13=\frac{M_{2}M_{12}}{M_{4}\,M_{6}},\quad 151 = \frac{M_1\,M_{15}}{M_{3}\,M_{5}},\quad 241 = \frac{M_{4}\,M_{24}}{M_{8}\,M_{12}},\quad 61681 = \frac{M_{4}\,M_{40}}{M_{8}\,M_{20}},\quad 15790321= \frac{M_{4}\,M_{56}}{M_{8}\,M_{28}},\quad 4278255361 = \frac{M_{8}\,M_{80}}{M_{16}\,M_{40}},\quad 4363953127297= \frac{M_{7}\,M_{98}}{M_{14}\,M_{49}}$$
and,

$$19=\frac{M_{3}\,M_{18}}{3M_{6}\,M_{9}},\quad 41=\frac{M_{2}^2M_{20}}{M_{4}^2\,M_{10}},\quad 337 = \frac{M_{21}}{M_{3}^2\,M_{7}},\quad 87211=\frac{M_{9}\,M_{54}}{3M_{18}\,M_{27}},\quad 22366891=\frac{M_{13}\,M_{78}}{3M_{26}\,M_{39}}$$
and,

$$5419 = \frac{M_{2}\,M_{3}\,M_{7}\,M_{42}}{M_{1}\,M_{6}\,M_{14}\,M_{21}},\quad 18837001= \frac{M_{6}\,M_{9}\,M_{15}\,M_{90}}{M_{3}\,M_{18}\,M_{30}\,M_{45}},\quad  4562284561=\frac{M_{8}\,M_{12}\,M_{20}\,M_{120}}{M_{4}\,M_{24}\,M_{40}\,M_{60}}$$

> **Question:**
>   Can we express in a similar manner the rest?: 
>   $$29, 37, 61, 109, 113, 397, 1321, 1613, 2113$$

**P.S.** As Bailey pointed out, their list for $p<2^{43}$ is not complete. For example, they missed the small prime, $\displaystyle p= 331 = \frac{M_{2}\,M_{3}\,M_{5}\,M_{30}}{M_{1}\,M_{6}\,M_{10}\,M_{15}}$.

Comment: Sequence [A104885](https://oeis.org/A104885) is incomplete for primes $p<10^3$ since $$\frac{M_{72}}{M_{36}}=\frac{2^{72}-1}{2^{26}-1} = 17\times241\times433\times38737$$ and the third factor, $p=433$, is missing in the list.

Comment: I think not. $M_n$ is divisible by both $29$ and $113$ iff $n$ is divisble by $28$. Same with $37$ and $109$ and $M_{36}$. Same with $61$ and $1321$ and $M_{60}$. Same with $397$ and $2113$ and $M_{44}$.